# how to mask the id in url (codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my routes i have change the url

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Customer';
$route['register'] = 'staff/register'; 
$route['admin'] = 'user/display_admin_dashboard';
$route['customer/display_medicine_prescription'] = 'customer/display_medicine_prescription/(:any)';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route[LOGIN_PAGE] = 'examples/login';
```

customer/display_medicine_notification/14

this is my url how hide the id (14)

Comment: Store some kind of `hashed_id` into db when storing data and collect data with get by `hashed_id`. Something like `md5(time().md5($id))`.

Comment: You cannot. If could, how to let the controller know what the id is going to query? To hide, @Tpojka is a great idea.

Comment: ya that's good but ,don't show the id the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try it i think its work

> $route["display_medicine_prescription/([0-9]+)/(.*)"] ="customer/display_medicine_prescription";

Answer (score 1):

U can use slug-name ex :

http://localhost/display_medicine_prescription/(slug-name)

route.php

```
$route['display_medicine_prescription/(:any)'] = 'customer/display_medicine_prescription';
```

And your model :

```
 public function display_medicine_prescription($slug = FALSE){
        if ($slug === FALSE){
                $query = $this->db->get('medecine');
                return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('medecine', array('slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
```